# Failed to launch browser | Access denied | Google API Authorization

Tags: wcf

Our expectation is to upload a document on Google drive if uses is logged in to the system. If first time user system will open a popup for login credentials. Below code is working fine on my development environment (localhost) but not on QA server when I publish the code on QA server.

Just for info, we are using Google API for authorization.

Below is my code snippet:

```
       Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service = null;
        try
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            string credPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               new ClientSecrets
               {
                   ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_id"],
                   ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_secret"],
               },
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            // Create Drive API service.
            service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return service;
```

Below is an error message:
"Failed to launch browser with \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=123&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54597%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive\" for authorization.