# Unable to register Google API access in Visual Studio (Failed to launch browser)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've been trying to register a Google API access in order to distribute my archive, but I've kept getting a strange error, which is similar to the one mentioned here:
[Failed to launch browser | Access denied | Google API Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104820/failed-to-launch-browser-access-denied-google-api-authorization)

> Google Play Store: Authorize: Failed to launch browser with...

[image: error]

I'm unsure if it's related, but I've also noticed that all of the links in Visual Studio don't work (for ex. "Project Site" in NuGet Package Manager). They just don't open.
I've tried running Visual Studio as an administrator - it didn't change anything.
Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I simply did not have a default browser set in Windows.